# react-vega - how to add dropdown menu to react app to chart without vega-embed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vega

Here is an example of Vega chart with menu:
https://bl.ocks.org/domoritz/raw/455e1c7872c4b38a58b90df0c3d7b1b9/

In this example chart is generated with vega-embed and has a dropdown menu.
[image]

I use react-vega for charts.
Here is an example of my chart that uses react-vega:
https://codesandbox.io/s/m7xp6ro5wx

Question 1: What is the best way to add menu to this chart (react-vega chart in react app)?
Question 2: How to change the style of this menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Vega-embed, you can always use Vanilla React and other components library to develop your own dropdown menu.  (This is beyond the scope of the Vega / React-Vega library.)